# How to customise basic select to a chip select using Material UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I would like to achieve the following filter chips using material UI.

[image]

Currently, I am using the provided material component for basic select (https://mui.com/components/selects/)

```
<FormControl fullWidth>
  <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Age</InputLabel>
  <Select
    labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
    id="demo-simple-select"
    value={age}
    label="Age"
    onChange={handleChange}
  >
    <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
  </Select>
</FormControl>
```

[image]

And it looks like this.

How do I convert the provided BasicSelect to a chip-like filter (I'm new to customisation for material components). Probably need to use overrides. But I'm not sure where to begin.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the [API docs](https://mui.com/api/input-label/) for the component and add custom CSS rules there.

```
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/styles";

const ReactComponent = ({classes})
=> { 
return (
<FormControl fullWidth>
  <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Age</InputLabel>
        <Select
            className={classes.Style1}
    labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
    id="demo-simple-select"
    value={age}
    label="Age"
    onChange={handleChange}
  >
    <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
  </Select>
</FormControl> )

}

export default withStyles(theme => ({
    style1: {
        "&.MuiInputLabel-root": {
      color: "red"
    },

}
}))(ReactComponent)
```